# angularjs $http with cache and interceptor

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-http

I'm trying to use angulars $http, with both a cache and an interceptor.

The quick question:
Currently when angular gets the answer from the server, it first caches it, and then it passes it through the interceptor.
Is it possible to force angular to first pass it through the interceptor and only then cache it?

The long issue:

The server responds every call with a format similar to:
{permission: BOOL, data:[...]}
In the interceptor response I check the permission, and if correct I throw it away and pass only the data field to the application level. If it fails I reject and popup an error, etc... (Maybe I should do it in a transformResponse function, but I'll endup facing the same issue).

Then for some API calls I'm requesting a bunch of resources like that:
/resource/ALL
And it obviously caches this request and answer, but what I want to do next is fake caching every resource that I received. 
So forthcoming calls to /resource/{some resource id} are already cached, cause I've already received it in the call where I requested ALL.

The problem I'm facing is, when I want to fake cache, on the application level, I lost the "{permission: BOOL" part, cause I've thrown it in the interceptor.

Some notes: 
1- Of course I could also fake the permission part, and just hardcode it, but I feel it's not an option since if I later add / modify / remove metadata it's another place I've to look at.
2- An other way would be to don't throw the metadata on the interceptor / transformResponse, but again this is not an option since I don't want to select the 'data' field every time I call $http on the application level.

So I think the best option for me would be to cache after the interceptor, and not before.

Hope I made the issue clear, and any answer is welcome!

Comment: Hi, this is an old question and I'm sure you've solved the issue long ago, but you should never rely on client-side checks for implementing access control. It's not secure: by the time your interceptor checks for the `permission` value, the data is already on the client where it could be retrieved by an attacker. Do you have access to the server code?

Comment: @BadIdeaException indeed yes; it's solved.
The permission flag was just to display an error on the client side, of course the data field was empty or null in case of false permission.